# Want to connect dataShort_out of DataConverter to an output file using python

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a waveform that contains a DataConverter and is connected to my node. I want to save the dataShort_out of the DataConverter to a file and write out some data. I am able to do this using the IDE and take a snapshot. I want to do the same thing using python. I am using RH 1.9.

```
>>> from ossie.utils import redhawk
>>> domain = redhawk.attach('REDHAWK_dev')
>>> devMgr = domain.devMgrs
>>> devMgr = devMgr[1]
>>> device = devMgr.devs
>>> device = devMgr.devs[1]
>>> test_wavform = domain.createApplication("/waveforms/Test/test.sad.xml")
>>> comp1=waveform.comps[0]
>>> comp1.name
'DataConverter'
>>> comp1_port=comp1.getPort('dataShort_out')
>>> comp1.start()
>>> from ossie.utils import sb
>>> sb.start()
>>> output_file = sb.FileSink('~/some_file.tmp')
>>> comp1.connect(output_file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/utils/model/__init__.py", line 255, in connect
raise RuntimeError, 'Multiple ports matched interfaces on connect, must specify providesPortName or usesPortName'
RuntimeError: Multiple ports matched interfaces on connect, must specify providesPortName or usesPortName
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to specify your port name on the "connect" call:

```
>>> comp1.connect(output_file, usesPortName='dataShort_out')
>>> output_file.start()
```